# Merge multiple files into a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've written a code to read multiple files, format the data and merge them into a single dataframe:

```
import os.path
import glob

def get_merged_file(flist, **kwargs):
    fdf=pd.DataFrame()
    for f in flist:
        df=pd.read_excel(f, **kwargs)
        df=df.iloc[4:-1]
        df.columns=df.iloc[0]
        df=df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
        df = df.iloc[:, :-4]
        fdf.append(df)
    return fdf

path='S:/random path'

fls = os.path.join(path, 'Report*.xls')

dff = get_merged_file(glob.glob(fls))
print(dff)
```

But this is returning

Empty DataFrame

Columns: []

Index: []

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1st assign it back `fdf=fdf.append(df)`

Comment: @Wen is correct.  However, I answered with what I think is a better pattern for you.

Comment: Thanks Wen, that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to have a function return a parsed dataframe and use `pd.concat` to put them altogether.

```
import os.path
import glob

def get_file(fp, **kwargs):
    df = pd.read_excel(f, **kwargs)
    df = df.iloc[4:-1]
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
    df = df.iloc[:, :-4]
    return df

path='S:/random path'

fls = os.path.join(path, 'Report*.xls')

dff = pd.concat([get_file(f) for f in glob.glob(fls)])
print(dff)
```

Comment: Why is this better than combining the two functions together?

Comment: Assuming more than 2 files, you are creating a master dataframe and appending to it for every file you get.  The pattern I gave has the same amount of parsing but let's pandas handle the combining in one step as opposed to n steps.

Comment: You can put the `pd.concat` in a function as well.  I'm just suggesting using `pd.concat` as opposed to a series of `append`